map frame doesn't exist, but the map topic has been successfully published, use the new GazeboSim Ros 2 Jazzy
I have problem with amcl localization: Map frame doesn't exist and return this:
[amcl-2] [INFO] [1734294170.213512210] [amcl]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'laser_scan_link' at time 124.000 for reason 'the timestamp on the message is earlier than all the data in the transform cache'
[amcl-2] [INFO] [1734294171.496397986] [amcl]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'laser_scan_link' at time 125.000 for reason 'the timestamp on the message is earlier than all the data in the transform cache'


so, I trying run nav2 with robot in new Gazebo Sim (https://gazebosim.org/docs/latest/migrating_gazebo_classic_ros2_packages/),
I'm using:
ROS2 Jazzy
Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
ros2 control
gazebo Sim (new)
my code:
localization.py
# Copyright (c) 2018 Intel Corporation
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

import os

from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory

from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument, SetEnvironmentVariable
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from nav2_common.launch import RewrittenYaml


def generate_launch_description():
    # Get the launch directory
    bringup_dir = get_package_share_directory('go1_description')

    namespace = LaunchConfiguration('namespace')
    map_yaml_file = LaunchConfiguration('map')
    use_sim_time = LaunchConfiguration('use_sim_time')
    autostart = LaunchConfiguration('autostart')
    params_file = LaunchConfiguration('params_file')
    lifecycle_nodes = ['map_server', 'amcl']

    # Map fully qualified names to relative ones so the node's namespace can be prepended.
    # In case of the transforms (tf), currently, there doesn't seem to be a better alternative
    # https://github.com/ros/geometry2/issues/32
    # https://github.com/ros/robot_state_publisher/pull/30
    # TODO(orduno) Substitute with `PushNodeRemapping`
    #              https://github.com/ros2/launch_ros/issues/56
    remappings = [('/tf', 'tf'),
                  ('/tf_static', 'tf_static'),
                  ('/scan','scan')
                  ]

    # Create our own temporary YAML files that include substitutions
    param_substitutions = {
        'use_sim_time': use_sim_time,
        'yaml_filename': map_yaml_file}

    configured_params = RewrittenYaml(
        source_file=params_file,
        root_key=namespace,
        param_rewrites=param_substitutions,
        convert_types=True)

    return LaunchDescription([
        # Set env var to print messages to stdout immediately
        SetEnvironmentVariable('RCUTILS_LOGGING_BUFFERED_STREAM', '1'),

        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            'namespace', default_value='',
            description='Top-level namespace'),

        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            'map',
            default_value=os.path.join(bringup_dir, 'maps', 'warehouse_map.yaml'),
            description='Full path to map yaml file to load'),

        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            'use_sim_time', default_value='true',
            description='Use simulation (Gazebo) clock if true'),

        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            'autostart', default_value='true',
            description='Automatically startup the nav2 stack'),

        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            'params_file',
            default_value=os.path.join(bringup_dir, 'config', 'nav2_params.yaml'),
            description='Full path to the ROS2 parameters file to use'),

        Node(
            package='nav2_map_server',
            executable='map_server',
            name='map_server',
            output='screen',
            parameters=[configured_params],
            remappings=remappings
            ),

        Node(
            package='nav2_amcl',
            executable='amcl',
            name='amcl',
            output='screen',
            parameters=[configured_params],
            remappings=remappings
            ),

        Node(
            package='nav2_lifecycle_manager',
            executable='lifecycle_manager',
            name='lifecycle_manager_localization',
            output='screen',
            parameters=[{'use_sim_time': use_sim_time},
                        {'autostart': autostart},
                        {'node_names': lifecycle_nodes}])
    ])

urdf:
    <gazebo reference="laser_scan_link">
        <material>Gazebo/Black</material>

        <sensor name="laser_scan_link" type="gpu_lidar">
            <pose> 0 0 0 0 0 0 </pose>
            <visualize>false</visualize>
            <update_rate>1</update_rate>
            <lidar>
                <scan>
                    <horizontal>
                        <samples>360</samples>
                        <min_angle>-3.14</min_angle>
                        <max_angle>3.14</max_angle>
                    </horizontal>
                </scan>
                <range>
                    <min>0.3</min>
                    <max>12</max>
                </range>
            </lidar>
            <topic>/scan</topic>
            <gz_frame_id>laser_scan_link</gz_frame_id>
        </sensor>
    </gazebo>
    
     <joint name='laser_scan' type='fixed'>
        <parent link="trunk"/>,
        <child link="laser_scan_link"/>
        <origin xyz="0.263 0.0 0.077" rpy="0 0 0" />
    </joint>

    <link name="laser_scan_link">
        <inertial>
            <mass value="0.001"/>
            <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
            <inertia ixx="0.0001" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.0001" iyz="0" izz="0.0001"/>
        </inertial>
        <visual>
            <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length="0.01" radius="0.018" />
            </geometry>
            <!-- <material name="red"/> -->
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length="0.01" radius="0.018" />
            </geometry>
        </collision>
    </link>

and amcl params:
amcl:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: true
    alpha1: 0.0001  
    alpha2: 0.0001
    alpha3: 0.0001
    alpha4: 0.0001
    alpha5: 0.0001
    base_frame_id: "base_link"
    beam_skip_distance: 0.5
    beam_skip_error_threshold: 0.9
    beam_skip_threshold: 0.3
    do_beamskip: false
    global_frame_id: "map"
    lambda_short: 0.1
    laser_likelihood_max_dist: 2.0
    laser_max_range: 100.0
    laser_min_range: -1.0
    laser_model_type: "likelihood_field"
    max_beams: 60
    max_particles: 2000
    min_particles: 500
    odom_frame_id: "odom"
    map_frame_id: "map"
    pf_err: 0.02
    pf_z: 0.85
    recovery_alpha_fast: 0.0
    recovery_alpha_slow: 0.0
    resample_interval: 2
    robot_model_type: "nav2_amcl::DifferentialMotionModel"
    save_pose_rate: 0.5
    sigma_hit: 0.02
    tf_broadcast: true
    transform_tolerance: 0.5
    update_min_a: 0.06
    update_min_d: 0.025
    z_hit: 0.7
    z_max: 0.001
    z_rand: 0.059
    z_short: 0.24
    scan_topic: /scan

world file:
<sdf version="1.6">
  <world name="empty">
    <physics name="1ms" type="ignored">
      <max_step_size>0.001</max_step_size>
      <real_time_factor>1.0</real_time_factor>
    </physics>
    <plugin
      filename="gz-sim-physics-system"
      name="gz::sim::systems::Physics">
    </plugin>
    <plugin
      filename="gz-sim-user-commands-system"
      name="gz::sim::systems::UserCommands">
    </plugin>
    <plugin
      filename="gz-sim-scene-broadcaster-system"
      name="gz::sim::systems::SceneBroadcaster">
    </plugin>
    <plugin
      filename="gz-sim-sensors-system"
      name="gz::sim::systems::Sensors">
      <render_engine>ogre2</render_engine>
    </plugin>
    <plugin
      filename="gz-sim-contact-system"
      name="gz::sim::systems::Contact">
    </plugin>

    <light type="directional" name="sun">
      <cast_shadows>true</cast_shadows>
      <pose>0 0 10 0 0 0</pose>
      <diffuse>0.8 0.8 0.8 1</diffuse>
      <specular>0.2 0.2 0.2 1</specular>
      <attenuation>
        <range>1000</range>
        <constant>0.9</constant>
        <linear>0.01</linear>
        <quadratic>0.001</quadratic>
      </attenuation>
      <direction>-0.5 0.1 -0.9</direction>
    </light>

    <model name="ground_plane">
      <static>true</static>
      <link name="link">
        <collision name="collision">
          <geometry>
            <plane>
              <normal>0 0 1</normal>
              <size>100 100</size>
            </plane>
          </geometry>
        </collision>
        <visual name="visual">
          <geometry>
            <plane>
              <normal>0 0 1</normal>
              <size>100 100</size>
            </plane>
          </geometry>
          <material>
            <ambient>0.8 0.8 0.8 1</ambient>
            <diffuse>0.8 0.8 0.8 1</diffuse>
            <specular>0.8 0.8 0.8 1</specular>
          </material>
        </visual>
      </link>
    </model>
  </world>
</sdf>

gz_bridge:
- ros_topic_name: "clock"
  gz_topic_name: "clock"
  ros_type_name: "rosgraph_msgs/msg/Clock"
  gz_type_name: "gz.msgs.Clock"
  direction: GZ_TO_ROS

# gz topic published by Sensors plugin
- ros_topic_name: "scan"
  gz_topic_name: "scan"
  ros_type_name: "sensor_msgs/msg/LaserScan"
  gz_type_name: "gz.msgs.LaserScan"
  direction: GZ_TO_ROS

- ros_topic_name: "scan"
  gz_topic_name: "scan"
  ros_type_name: "sensor_msgs/msg/LaserScan"
  gz_type_name: "gz.msgs.LaserScan"
  direction: ROS_TO_GZ

# gz topic published by Sensors plugin (Camera)
# - ros_topic_name: "camera/camera_info"
#   gz_topic_name: "camera/camera_info"
#   ros_type_name: "sensor_msgs/msg/CameraInfo"
#   gz_type_name: "gz.msgs.CameraInfo"
#   direction: GZ_TO_ROS

# gz topic published by IMU plugin
- ros_topic_name: "imu_plugin/out"
  gz_topic_name: "imu_plugin/out"
  ros_type_name: "sensor_msgs/msg/Imu"
  gz_type_name: "gz.msgs.IMU"
  direction: GZ_TO_ROS

# gz topic published by DiffDrive plugin
- ros_topic_name: "odom"
  gz_topic_name: "odom"
  ros_type_name: "nav_msgs/msg/Odometry"
  gz_type_name: "gz.msgs.Odometry"
  direction: GZ_TO_ROS

# gz topic published by DiffDrive plugin
- ros_topic_name: "tf"
  gz_topic_name: "tf"
  ros_type_name: "tf2_msgs/msg/TFMessage"
  gz_type_name: "gz.msgs.Pose_V"
  direction: GZ_TO_ROS


# gz topic published by JointState plugin
- ros_topic_name: "joint_states"
  gz_topic_name: "joint_states"
  ros_type_name: "sensor_msgs/msg/JointState"
  gz_type_name: "gz.msgs.Model"
  direction: GZ_TO_ROS

